# Does Gods using other God's name also happens in real life?

Tags: culture, noragami

In Noragami, some Gods uses other God's name for their business name. An example of this practice is Bimbo-gami, Kofuku, using Ebisu's name. Is such practice limited to the world within Noragami? Or does it stems from the real world? In other words, does some of the Japanese Gods in the real world also do such practice?